How to convert list of calendar dates into to_datetime in pandas
I have some function which returns list of holidays. The list looks so
['30 May 2024','1 May 2024', '29 Aug 2024', '14 Aug 2024', '19 May 2024'] 

When iam trying to do
print(pd.to_datetime(['30 May 2024','1 May 2024', '29 Aug 2024', '14 Aug 2024', '19 May 2024']))

Error
============================================================================================== RESTART: C:\Users\Bhargav\Downloads\gapi.py =============================================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bhargav\Downloads\gapi.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(pd.to_datetime(['30 May 2024','1 May 2024', '29 Aug 2024', '14 Aug 2024', '19 May 2024']))
  File "C:\Users\Bhargav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 1099, in to_datetime
    result = convert_listlike(argc, format)
  File "C:\Users\Bhargav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 433, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    return _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, utc, format, exact, errors)
  File "C:\Users\Bhargav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 467, in _array_strptime_with_fallback
    result, tz_out = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors, utc=utc)
  File "strptime.pyx", line 501, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
  File "strptime.pyx", line 451, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
  File "strptime.pyx", line 583, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime._parse_with_format
ValueError: time data "29 Aug 2024" doesn't match format "%d %B %Y", at position 2. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

But But it works perfect with this list
print(pd.to_datetime(['30 Dec 2024','1 May 2024', '29 Aug 2024', '14 Aug 2024', '19 May 2024']))

I get
============================================================================================== RESTART: C:\Users\Bhargav\Downloads\gapi.py =============================================================================================
DatetimeIndex(['2024-12-30', '2024-05-01', '2024-08-29', '2024-08-14',
               '2024-05-19'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

Am i missing anything here??

As written in the error message, use format='mixed': print(pd.to_datetime(['30 May 2024','1 May 2024', '29 Aug 2024', '14 Aug 2024', '19 May 2024'], format='mixed'))

But same list just swapped the dates, its works fine..\

Well, this might be dur to how pandas infers the dates. This is powerful but sometimes breaks. Better pass an explicit format or mixed. Here it's due to May. I'll give you more details

The issue is due to having May as a first date. May is both the full (%B) and abbreviated (%b) name of the month.
When pandas tried to infer the format, it decided to use %d %B %Y, which is correct for May but not for Aug (it would have needed %b). As described here this is done by pandas.tseries.api.guess_datetime_format:
from pandas.tseries.api import guess_datetime_format

guess_datetime_format('30 May 2024') # '%d %B %Y'

When passing Dec/Aug as a first date, this doesn't cause the issue:
guess_datetime_format('30 Dec 2024') # '%d %b %Y'

If you use format='mixed' or format='%d %b %Y', this will work fine:
pd.to_datetime(['30 May 2024','1 May 2024', '29 Aug 2024', '14 Aug 2024', '19 May 2024'], format='mixed')

DatetimeIndex(['2024-05-30', '2024-05-01', '2024-08-29', '2024-08-14',
               '2024-05-19'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


That makes sense now -  when the first date has "May" as the month, the chances of full-month-format (%B) being correct are - difficult to estimate
